# Get opened tabs information of Firefox?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, firefox, dde

I'm trying to write a simple program that should search in Firefox window for duplicated tabs (checking the url of the tab) and then close the found duplicated tabs.

The idea is simple, but the implementation seems a nightmare.

Doing a lot of researchs messing with WinAPI I've found [nDde](http://ndde.codeplex.com/) library, which could retrieve the url of **the current tab** easy like this example:

VB.NET

```
    Imports NDde.Client

    Using dde As New DdeClient("Firefox", "WWW_GetWindowInfo")

        dde.Connect()

        Dim Url As String = dde.Request("URL", Integer.MaxValue).
                                Trim({ControlChars.NullChar, ControlChars.Quote, ","c})

        MessageBox.Show(Url)

        dde.Disconnect()

    End Using
```

C#:

```
using (DdeClient dde = new DdeClient("Firefox", "WWW_GetWindowInfo")) {

    dde.Connect();

    string Url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue).Trim({
        ControlChars.NullChar,
        ControlChars.Quote,
        ','
    });

    MessageBox.Show(Url);

    dde.Disconnect();

}

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//Conversion powered by NRefactory.
//Twitter: @telerik
//Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
//=======================================================
```

But my knowledges about this library or dde in general are zero, so what I'm doing by the moment is sending **ctrl+Tab** keys to Firefox to change between tabs to get the url of each tab and then close duplicated founds sending **ctrl+w**, but this way I have not a reference point to know which tab was the "starting point" to know when I need to stop the dup-tab searching 'cause the first checked url could have a duplicated tab too, and also I can't know the exact number of opened tabs to have an Index reference.

I'm lost.

My question is, this library (or another library related to dde, or another totally different way) could retrieve at least one of those things in a dynamic way?:

> · The url of the first tab, I mean the tab that is at the top-left, the first of all opened tabs.
>
> · The total amount count of opened tabs.
>
> · The url of all tabs.

Comment: Isn't that like _breaking_ into the user's privacy??

Comment: @Sunny I don't know, but it's a tool for my only and personal use then in that case I think I'm nor breaking any term 'cause I can do whatever I want with my own privacy..., thanks for comment!

Comment: I think it might be much easier to do this as a Firefox extension: [Building a Firefox Extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Building_an_Extension)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much expertise here, but I think such a script can be misused and thus most browsers might not allow it. There must exist something similar to the same origin policy here. And sorry again, I'm  just presenting a concern here.
& I Agree with @Orilux as that will require user permission before installing.

Comment: @Orilux is correct, write a Firefox add-on. Or don't; there are already a bunch of Firefox extensions which can close duplicate tabs for you (among other things)...

Comment: @nmaier, thanks, I've found one: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duplicate-tabs-closer/

Comment: If it violates the user's privacy then why did Firefox (and just about every major Windows web browser [except for Chrome now]) opt to support the DDE interface to allowing for querying for this kind of thing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is already a Firefox extension that:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duplicate-tabs-closer/

Comment: Did not answer the actual question.  Firefox supports this via DDE (lots of third party apps do it, and claim they're doing it with DDE) -- but the only code samples we've seen are for the currently selected tab.  We want to be able to enumerate all of them as a collection of strings in .NET.